# the read function in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have this code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char x =(char)in.read();
        char y =(char)in.read();
        char z =(char)in.read();
        System.out.print(x+y+z);
    }
}
```

and this input:

```
1
2
```

and the output is:

```
109
```

Why do I get this output?
I can't understand how read function works.
I tried using the skip function and didn't get the right answer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading your input as characters. Your input is three characters (1, 2, and line feed):

- `1` with an ASCII value of 49.
- `2` with an ASCII value of 50.
- `line feed` with an ASCII value of 10.

Then you add those three chars by their ASCII value, giving a total of 109.

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII. See [Character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Comment: @TomBlodget true, but Unicode is backwards-compatible with ASCII, so, if you have a text made out of only ASCII characters, they're also the same text as Unicode code points.

Comment: So why mention ASCII? Do you write code that uses it at all?

Comment: @TomBlodget it's just simpler to talk about ASCII when you stay within the bounds of ASCII. And personally I write a lot of code that deals with protocols that need ASCII-only or due escaping mechanisms.

Comment: @kumesana Okay, and you could probably cite the RFCs or other relevant specifications. But someone learning Java (JavaScript, C#, VB4, VBA, F#, VB,  …) is using Unicode and should come to know that.

Comment: I'm sorry for ASCII. I debated while writing it and went for it instead of Unicode.

Comment: the second problem is that i can't enter the third letter .the output appear immediately after the second input

Comment: @Abdalla you're gonna have ton check if a char you read is an end of line, and if so ignore it and keep reading. read() won't do that automatically for you, when there is an end of line, read() will give you that end of line.

Comment: @Abdalla or you could just type in as input, `123`, without pressing space or enter or anything, just `123`. That way, read() will first read the `1`, then next read() will read the `2`, and third read() will read the `3`

Comment: @TheImpaler Respecting your current vote count of 18.3k, I am not going to change your answer, but may I suggest you add a base to “value” despite it being implied? For example, ASCII value of 49 (base 10). It might help clear up the confusion with UTF-8, UTF-16 etc. If you just add it up, 109 is always the result in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've misunderstood how the character is being returned when [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) is called.

> The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

The `read` method returns an `int` so it can return the Unicode code for the character.  For simple letters and numbers, Unicode overlaps ASCII, where `1` is 49, `2` is 50, and a newline character is 10.  The sum of those codes is 109.

Options:

- Use a [`Scanner` and its `nextInt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--).
- Use [`BufferedReader`'s `readLine` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) and parse the strings to integers with `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: the second problem is that i can't enter the third letter .the output appear immediately after the second input